# Android - Progressivly show image from bottom to top

Tags: java, android, imageview

Essentially what I have is a transparent image that I want to slowly "fill in" from bottom to top over time.

I'm aware of using `ClipDrawable` and the its `level` value, but that would fill in from the top. Is there any way to reverse that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClipDrawable` works just fine for this. Just use `Gravity.BOTTOM` when you create it.

```
Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.my_drawable);
ClipDrawable clip = new ClipDrawable(d, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: I know it's late, but there's a way to reverse this animation?